# Linux - как посмотреть права на файлы, если их очень много

Tags: linux

В директории 100 000 файлов, поэтому ls -l просто забивает консоль, в итоге она показывает последние максимум 100 файлов. Возможно ли посмотреть права не через консоль/посмотреть права на определенный диапазон файлов/в крайнем случае на какой-то один файл? Гугл ответа не дал.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно всегда перенаправить в файл, где то так:

```
ls  -al > myfile.txt
```

а можно использовать пейджер:

```
ls -al | less
```

выход с пейджера - `q`, поиск - слеш и текст. `n`/`N` для следующему-предыдущему результату. Этого хватит 90 процентов задач. Потом можно ещё `&` использовать для фильтрации (работает как слеш, просто фильтрует вывод, оставляя только строки, которые соответствуют фильтру. Может быть медленным, если строк много.)